# Converting a point file, into a smoother set?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, flood

I am currently attempting to show how a coastal area was flooded from the 2010 Mentawai Ocean tsunami on the Pagai Islands. I currently have a DEM and a DEM which I have sourced from a point data set, and I am attempting to show how the coast was flooded using these data points. However, I cannot seem to find out how to show the area which was flooded using the specified water heights. To provide some information I have attached the image here.

.[image]

I want to be able to 'smooth out' the point data sets, so that I can explicitly show which areas were flooded. I also have a horizontal inundation data set, so I can depict how far in land the tsunami water inundated the land. However, I am unaware as to how I can combine these data sets to show exactly how far flooding went and how tall flooding was.

Comment: Are the water depths in the point file? When you say "smooth out" do you mean filling the gaps between the points with information?

Answer (score 1):

if you already have a point vector layer, you can extract the information from your DEM to your point layer using the Spatial Analyst tool *Extract to Point*. You can use *Spatial Join* to join your horizontal-flooding vector layer. This way each point will have the elevation at ground level and information whether or not it was flooded.